# symstore error: Couldn't create "...\000Admin\0000000001". Win32 error 80: The file exists"

Tags: c++, windows, symbols, symstore

We're publishing symbols to our symbol server (S3 as a network drive) as part of our build process.  The first publish worked but now the symstore task fails with this error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\symstore" add /r /f C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\mybuild\symbols-source\*.* /s Z:\symbol-server
Finding ID... 0000000001
SYMSTORE ERROR: Class: Server. Desc: Couldn't create "Z:\symbol-server\000Admin\0000000001". Win32 error 80: The file exists.
```

I'm looking for help resolving this error or reasons why it's happening. I've reviewed the symstore documentation and searched for others running into this problem and have come up empty handed.

Comment: Try using a different destination (i.e. not S3) to narrow down the cause.

Comment: I'll try that.  I suspect it isn't S3 but its worth trying.  I think we're making the mistake elsewhere thugh because this is part of a CI job that did succeed once.  The first time we added symstore to the job, it worked and symbols ended up on S3.  The 2-N times this job has run, it as failed with the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was a permissions related issue.  The build server's S3 account didn't have permissions to delete or edit files, only to add new ones.  Once the permissions were fixed, the issue was resolved.